# "Invalid development certificate found" on Mac

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain

My GoogleFoo simply is not strong enough to find a solution.

I am a recent convert to Mac (don't judge). Using Visual Studio 20##? on my PC (C#), when I build and run, Life if great. On my newly acquired Mac-Mini, running Visual Studio 2019 for Mac (C#), when I build and run (following an uber easy code along video), I get "Invalid development certificate found".

Bottom line, I'm lost, Apple Support is no help on this issue. I am pretty confident my keyboard actuator. Any help, even it is a "Here let me Google that for you" would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to this link => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#troubleshoot-certificate-problems

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
```

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

It worked after I closed all web browsers and relaunched app.

Comment: running both commands caused: security: SecKeychainItemCopyAccess: The specified item is no longer valid. It may have been deleted from the keychain.
dont run these commands as it will erase the dotnet certificate